# Java singleton, any alternatives for this usecase?

Tags: java, singleton

I am providing a Java service responsible for abstracting away the connection to a TCP server. The idea is to avoid opening a new connection whenever `connect()` is called.

For me, this is the definition of the singleton pattern usage. Still, given the criticism around it, I would like to ask if there are other better and meaningful alternatives, specifically for such cases.

```
public class TCPConnectionService {
    private static TCPConnectionService instance;
    private final TCPConnection connection;
    private TCPConnectionService() {
        this.connection = connect();
    }
    public synchronized static TCPConnectionService getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new TCPConnectionService();
        }

        return instance;
    }
    private TCPConnection connect() {...}
}
```